# How to solve for $x$ in the equation $x\log(x)=A$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a standard way of solving equation of the form $x\log(x)=A$, where $A$ is a constant?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a solution in terms of elementary functions, but:

$$x\ln(x)=\text{a}$$

Then:

1. When $\text{a}=0$:
   $$x=1$$
2. When $\text{a}\ne0$:
   $$x=\exp\left(\text{W}(\text{a})\right)$$
3. When $\text{a}\ne0$ and $\Im\left[\text{W}_1(\text{a})\right]\le0$:
   $$x=\exp\left(\text{W}_1(\text{a})\right)$$
4. When $\text{a}\ne0$ and $\Im\left[\text{W}_{-1}(\text{a})\right]+\pi>0$:
   $$x=\exp\left(\text{W}_{-1}(\text{a})\right)$$

Where $\text{W}(z)$ is the product log function and $\text{W}_k(z)$ is the analytic continuation of the product log function.

Answer (score 0):

Not in terms of elementary functions. The result is 
$$x = e^{W(A)}$$
where $W$ is the product logarithm function.

Comment: can you explain how this is obtained?

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed form analytic solution in terms of elementary functions.  The standard way is to do this numerically, using Newton's method: Start with a guess of $x_0 = 1$ then iterate on

$$
x_n = x_{n-1} + \frac{A-x_{n-1}\log x_{n-1}}{1+\log x_{n-1}}
$$

The converges rapidly ((each error term goes like the square of the previous error term, for positive $A$) to the answer.